# Convert returned values to a specific type

Tags: go

I'm just getting started with go and I've come across the following "problem".

I'm using a function which returns 4 unsigned 32 bit integers, and I was wondering what the best method to convert these values to 8 bit integers when I'm assigning them. (Or if it is possible). I have got it to work by assigning them to uint32, then converting them after that but I was wondering if there is a more concise way of doing it.

Example:

```
r, g, b, _ := image.At(x, y).RGBA() // ideally convert them at this stage
```

So Image.At returns uint32, but I would like r,g,b to be uint8

Thanks

Comment: The [`RGBA`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Uniform.RGBA) function returns the integers in `uint32`. What is the problem with manually converting them to `uint8`? Also, what is wrong with `uint32`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go has no syntax for what you want there. You're best bet is to just do it in the next line down.

```
rbig, gbig, bbig := image.At(x, y).RGBA()
r, g, b := uint8(rbig), uint8(gbig), uint8(bbig)
```

If that really annoys you though then just make a helper function

```
func convert(i, j, k, _ uint32) (uint8, uint8, uint8) { return uint8(i), uint8(j), uint8(k) }
r, g, b := convert(image.At(x, y).RGBA())
```

Still a minimum of two lines but you can reuse the function anywhere you need it and the call site might look a little cleaner to you.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for the advice. I'll probably go the function route.